# Kotlin: Is local function passed to inlined functions as parameter inlined?

Tags: kotlin, inline

When passing a lambda or anonymous function to inlined functions as a parameter, it's quite simple, the code is pasted to the calling position, but when passing a local function as a parameter, the result seems different(shown as below). I wonder if it's inlined? Why or why not?

For example:

```
inline fun foo(arg: () -> Int): Int {
    return arg()
}

fun bar(): Int {
    return 0
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    foo(::bar)
}
```

And decompiled Java code:

```
public final class InlinedFuncKt {
   public static final int foo(@NotNull Function0 arg) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(arg, "arg");
      return ((Number)arg.invoke()).intValue();
   }

   public static final int bar() {
      return 0;
   }

   public static final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(args, "args");
      bar();
   }
}
```

Comment: If it is already a function, not a closure, why would you want to inline it? No new object is allocated anyways

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot, but I'm still not clear about closure, I have experience in Java only.

Comment: My point is that inlining in this case does not affect semantics or performance, so you shouldn't really care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar()` is **not** declared to be *inlined*. So why would you expect it to be inlined?!

In other words: it would be simply wrong that the signature of method A affects (implicitly) the signature of another method B.

Your idea would (somehow) affect "semantics" of bar() - just because you used `bar()` as argument to another method call.

Comment: Thank you, `bar()` has its own right to decide its behavior, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

As you can in the [decompiled code](https://javap.yawk.at/#TngSAt/procyon), kotlin does not inline `bar` in your case, but it does inline it if it is declared as `inline fun bar()`.

The rule is that lambdas are inlined when they are passed to an inlined function. In all other cases like passing a function reference or a lambda object, no inlining is done.